# nginx deny rule and allow rule not working

Tags: nginx

first i have this in my nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /home/user/files;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name mydomain.com;

    location / {
        autoindex on;
       }

    #this option will allow auto index on video directory
     location ~ ^/video {
                auth_basic            "Restricted";
                auth_basic_user_file  /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
                include /etc/nginx/conf.d/php;
                autoindex on;
                autoindex_exact_size on;
}
    #only spesific ip allow to download files in video directory
    location ~ ^/video/* {
               autoindex off;
               allow myip;
               deny all;
       }

}
```

it seems **allow** rules is not working, i still got 403 when i try to download the video files.

is there something wrong with my conf ?

Comment: Please change `^/video/*` to `^/video/.*`! Note the plus dot character before asterisk!

Comment: no , its still not working , now i can download the files, with or without allow ip on conf file

Comment: Replace the order of two (regexp) locations!

Comment: nothing change still downloadable

Answer (score 1):

Put them in the same `location` block.

```
location /video/ {
    auth_basic            "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file  /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    allow myip;
    deny all;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/php;
    autoindex on;
    autoindex_exact_size on;
}
```

I can't see why you are using regexp match (`location ~ regexp`) for the path where simple forward match would suffice, and mixing autoindex on/off for the same location.